# Rails 3 ActiveResource not escaping unicode in xml when sending request

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource, activesupport

We recently moved to rails 3.2.13.  We use ActiveResource to call a web service.  ActiveResoure will generate the xml payload.  We noticed that the new xml doesn't escape unicode character. For example:

```
  <name> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\testütestdev1.txt </name>
```

In rails 2.3, it will escape ü to &#252; :

```
  <name> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\test&#252;testdev1.txt <name>
```

After some investigation.  It looks like it is due to ActiveSuppport to_xml method which doesn't escape unicode character.  Has anyone had this issue and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Rack::Utils` for that

```
> Rack::Utils.escape("  <name> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\testütestdev1.txt </name>")
#=> "++%3Cname%3E+C%3ADocuments+and+SettingsAll+Users%09est%C3%BCtestdev1.txt+%3C%2Fname%3E"

> Rack::Utils.unescape(_)
#=> "  <name> C:Documents and SettingsAll Users\testütestdev1.txt </name>"
```

Comment: But the problem is that we can't do the escape myself because we are using active_resource to make a web service call which will generate the xml.